# Evaluate Values From Multiple Rows As Part of Aggregate or Window Function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I need to find a way to tell if a column has two specific values within a grouped/partitioned section.  Easiest to describe by example.  I have table "foo" with the following data:

```
ID | Indicator
1  | A
1  | B
1  | B
2  | C
2  | B
3  | A
3  | B
3  | B
3  | C
4  | A
4  | C
```

For my output I want a result of "A" if one of the rows in the group has Indicator "A". If not, then "C" if one of the rows Indicator is "C".  But in the case where the group has an Indicator of "A" and an Indicator of "C" I want a result of "X" for the group.  Given the data I want the following result:

```
ID | Result
1  | A
2  | C
3  | X
4  | X
```

The result of A or C (ID 1 and 2 in the example) can be done using a partition and windows function this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
                priority_indicator
  FROM (SELECT ID,
               first_value(Indicator) OVER
               (PARTITION BY ID
                    ORDER BY
                      CASE
                        WHEN Indicator = 'A' THEN
                          1
                        WHEN Indicator = 'C' THEN
                          2
                        ELSE
                          3
                      END
               ) priority_indicator
          FROM foo) a
```

How would you look at the values in multiple rows at once to return an "X" when there's both an "A" and a "C" in the Indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--test data
WITH foo(id,indicator) AS ( VALUES
  (1,'A'),
  (1,'B'),
  (1,'B'),
  (2,'C'),
  (2,'B'),
  (3,'A'),
  (3,'B'),
  (3,'B'),
  (3,'C'),
  (4,'A'),
  (4,'C')
), 
-- get all entries for each Id in indicator_set
agg AS (
  SELECT id,array_agg(DISTINCT(indicator)) AS indicator_set FROM foo
  GROUP BY id
)
-- actual query
SELECT id,
  CASE
    WHEN indicator_set @> '{A,C}' THEN 'X'
    WHEN indicator_set @> '{A}' THEN 'A'
    WHEN indicator_set @> '{C}' THEN 'C'
  END result
FROM agg;
```

Output:

```
 id | result 
----+--------
  1 | A
  2 | C
  3 | X
  4 | X
(4 rows)
```